# Caspio onSubmit issues

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

My company is using Caspio to handle backend, mainly because the folks working on it need a low code solution.  I have checked Caspio's user community for some similar bits but nothing is really fitting the bill.

What we have is an issue where we have an autocomplete field that some users are keying in fields with data and aren't using capitalization where they should be and that's creating some issues.  I am trying to add some JavaScript to keep this from being an issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/zk8hqwxv/ //full set of scripts

```js
document.getElementsByName("InsertRecordCreator")[0].onchange = document.getElementsByName("InsertRecordCreator")[0].style.textTransform = "capitalize";

function capitalize() {
  var value = document.getElementsByName('InsertRecordCreator')[0].value;
  var newVal = '';
  val = value.split(' ');
  for (var c = 0; c < val.length; c++) {
    newVal += val[c].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val[c].substring(1, val[c].length) + ' ';
  }
  document.getElementsByName('InsertRecordCreator')[0].value = newVal;
}

document.getElementsByName("InsertRecordClient")[0].onchange = document.getElementsByName("InsertRecordClient")[0].style.textTransform = "uppercase";

function capitalize2() {
  var value2 = document.getElementsByName('InsertRecordClient')[0].value2;
  var newVal2 = '';
  val2 = value2.split(' ');
  for (var c = 0; c < val2.length; c++) {
    newVal2 += val2[c].substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
  }
  document.getElementsByName('InsertRecordClient')[0].value2 = newVal2;
}

document.getElementById('caspioform').onsubmit = capitalize;
document.getElementById('caspioform').onsubmit = capitalize2;
```

I'm trying to use onSubmit to call up these functions but it only seems to be working on the first one.  Anyone see any obvious issues.  I haven't coded for a while so the rust is a bit thick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

document.getElementById("caspioform").onsubmit=function(){capitalize(); capitalize2();}

Comment: You should explain what the code does. Also, code should be indented with 4 spaces to format it correctly.

Comment: Please forgive the formatting, pgmann, I'm a newbie!  This is probably the only question I could ever answer in this forum!  Thanks for the tip.